# R-openNLP no word tokens annotations found

Tags: r, opennlp

I am trying to tag POS to the texts for the review texts downloaded from Yelp dataset challenge (Round 11). Listed below are the functions I wrote:

```
r <- unlist(lapply(rec_texts, function(x) { str_split(x, "\n") }))

R_tagPOS <-  function(x, ...) {
r <- as.String(x)
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
a2 <- Annotation(1L, "sentence", 1L, nchar(r))
a2 <- annotate(r, word_token_annotator, a2)
a3 <- annotate(r, Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator(), a2)
a3w <- a3[a3$type == "word"]
POStags <- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
POStagged <- paste(sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], POStags), collapse = " ")
list(POStagged = POStagged, POStags = POStags)
}

POS_R <- lapply(r, R_tagPOS)
```

But it return result like this:

```
Error in e(s, a) : no word token annotations found 
8.stop("no word token annotations found") 
7. e(s, a) 
6.paste(y$id, y$type, y$start, y$end, sep = "\r") 
5.merge.Annotation(a, e(s, a)) 
4.merge(a, e(s, a)) 
3.annotate(r, Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator(), a2) 
2.FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.lapply(r, R_tagPOS)
```

The rec_texts are review texts from Yelp dataset challenge.

```
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   2000 obs. of  1 variable:
$ text: chr  "Mix is such a beautiful restaurant and you have a gorgeous 
view of the strip while you're enjoying your dinner!"| 
__truncated__"WooooooHooooo 100th review!!!  I eat here all the time, 
but I've gotta take the chance to be the 100th review.\"| __truncated__ 
"My bf and I came for a small snack and some brews. We got the pretzel 
and cheese appetizer. The pretzel was ver"| __truncated__ "The food was 
amazing! This is a must for me now when I come visit Las Vegas! Everyone 
was very friendly. The ow"| __truncated__ ...
```

May I ask has anyone encounter this situation before or anyone know how to solve this problem? Im thinking it has something to do with the data. Because this code works just fine for another review text dataset provided by third party.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error message and in my case I had an empty element in my vector of strings.

Once I removed all empty elements from my vector it worked fine.

Comment: Could you enrich your answer to include more details, examples maybe? Otherwise this is better served as a comment to the question.