# Error in e(s, a) : no sentence token annotations found. Error while doing NER in R

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition, text-analytics-api

I am trying to do Named Entity Recognition in R. Its throwing below error after doing sentence token annotation and word token annotation. Cannot find a way out. Please help if anyone has faced the same error.

Below is my code followed by the error.

```
library(openNLP)
sent_token_annotator = Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
word_token_annotator = Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
pos_tag_annotator = Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
pos_annotation = NLP::annotate(wc_text1, list(pos_tag_annotator, sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
# Error in e(s, a) : no sentence token annotations found
```

Comment: Please be explicit about non-base libraries you are using. This is `openNLP`, right?

Comment: Yes i am using openNLP

Comment: Have the same error message. Using [this tutorial](https://slcladal.github.io/tagging.html#POS-Tagging_non-English_texts) that is based on ```NLP```and ```openNLP``` There are [no empty cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008586/r-opennlp-no-word-tokens-annotations-found) in my data. Googling around has not provided much insight (yet) --> else I might do the POS tagging in Python

Comment: **my trace back**  ```Error in e(s, a) : no sentence token annotations found
9.
stop("no sentence token annotations found")
8.
e(s, a)
7.
paste(y$id, y$type, y$start, y$end, sep = "\r")
6.
merge.Annotation(a, e(s, a))
5.
merge(a, e(s, a))
4.
NLP::annotate(x, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
3.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2.
lapply(Corpus, function(x) {
y1 <- NLP::annotate(x, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
y2 <- NLP::annotate(x, pos_tag_annotator, y1)
y2w <- subset(y2, type == "word") ...
1.
postag_de(object = LinkedBlau2$textClean)
```